# White glitch background before turning black in React

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap, background-color

I have a website mostly done with React-Bootstrap and I am kind of a beginner in this field. I want my background to be black in all the pages so I set it with `background-color:black !important;` in every page. I did a Navigation Bar with React-Bootstrap and now when I move through the pages, there is a white glitch before turning it to black.

I tried to put the style in html, to load it faster, changed the color in body with !important, even overridden the bootstrap variable for `background-color` but neither of these worked.

I know that the glitch between the pages would dissappear if I would use just React NavBar not Bootstrap one and I've tried it, but there is also a glitch when you reload the page and it bothers me.

Has anyone any idea what could cause it?

My navigation bar is pretty simple:

```
<Navbar className="navbar" expand="sm">

            <Navbar.Brand className="logo" href="#home" >React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
            <Navbar.Toggle className="toggle" aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
            <Navbar.Collapse className="navbar-links" id="responsive-navbar-nav" >
                <Nav className="ms-auto">
                    <Nav.Link className="navlink" href="home">Home</Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link className="navlink" href="documents">Documents</Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link className="navlink" href="about">About</Nav.Link>

                </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
</Navbar >
```

Later edit :

I tried in Google Chrome and it shows only sometimes ( 2-3 reloads), but still appears.

Comment: Try checking your page load time. The browser is essentially taking time to load which causes the page to flicker before displaying your content.

Comment: I inserted a loading page that appears 2.5 seconds and it still flashes before it appears. It also has black background.